# Mysql query to get posts with recent comments - including comment count

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to

1. Get posts where someone has commented in the past 15 days
2. Sort by comment count
3. Return the post id along with the total number of comments for relevant posts

This is what I have:

```
SELECT post.id, COUNT(DISTINCT postcomments.id) as comments
FROM posts
LEFT JOIN postcomments on postcomments.postid = post.id
WHERE postcomment.posted_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
GROUP BY post.id
HAVING comments > 0
ORDER BY comments DESC
```

The problem with my query is that my comment count only includes comments posted in the past 15 days, whereas I want the total number of comments for the posts. How can I achieve this in one query?

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=9eccd48662916866599852607a1b8e69

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT post.id, COUNT(DISTINCT postcomments.id) as comments
FROM posts
JOIN postcomments on postcomments.postid = post.id
GROUP BY post.id
HAVING MAX(postcomment.posted_at) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)
ORDER BY comments DESC
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I don't think so. They want only posts that have a comment in the last 15 days, but the total count of all comments for those posts.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen OP directly says: "whereas I want the total number of comments for the posts". And according to `where` clause it should be limited by recently commented posts

Comment: @ysth can you help me understand the use of MAX here and why it doesn't work without it (cannot find column posted_at in having clause)

Comment: `MAX` is getting the latest `posted_at` value. Your condition is within 15 days so `MAX(posted_at) >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)` is checking if a `post.id` last post date is within 15 days. If you move `MAX` and just plain `posted_at`, `HAVING` will return error because the column is not specified in `SELECT`. If you put the `posted_at` column inside `SELECT`, you'll also get error because it's not in the `GROUP BY`. If you put `posted_at` in `GROUP BY`, you'll get a different result. [See this example fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=cd7ff9b994880aec45659c42e00fd0a4)

Comment: If you look at the last query in the fiddle (my comment above), I've added `GROUP_CONCAT` over the `posted_at` columns to list out all the dates corresponding to the `post.id`; ordered by ascending date. I also added the `MAX(posted_at)` in `SELECT` so that you can see what is the last post date. Since `MAX(posted_at)` is a function (the column `posted_at` is just being used for the function), `HAVING` won't have a problem using it even if its not specified in `SELECT`. I apologize in advance if I missed or state something incorrect but that's how I understand it.

Comment: Specifically, since `MAX` is an aggregate function, a special type of function that returns a value for each `GROUP BY` group based on values from all the rows that make up the group.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want to use conditional aggregation here:

```sql
SELECT
    p.id,
    SUM(pc.posted_at >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 15 DAY)) AS comments
FROM posts p
LEFT JOIN postcomments pc ON pc.postid = p.id
GROUP BY
    p.id
HAVING
    COUNT(*) > 0
ORDER BY
    comments DESC;
```

The `comments` count should still be the same as before, except that now we assert the total number of comments, rather than just asserting comments within the last 15 days.